# How do I configure storage class on an existing k0s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, debian-buster

When I run `kos kubectl get storageclass` I notice it is not provisioned and I have to add it manually. I am little unsure though on the exact procedure. The [Documentation][https://docs.k0sproject.io/main/storage/] says k0s comes with OpenEBS installed. What I am unsure of is how to ***enable this extension*** in the config file.

My existing config file has this only (I assume this should be the default config file. Is this correct ?) :

```
spec:
  api:
    externalAddress
```

I have run `k0s stop` then amended the config file as follows:

```
spec:
  api:
    externalAddress
  extensions:
    storage:
      type: openebs_local_storage
```

After this config change I still get the same error they is no storageclass found for the cluster. Do I need to also reinstall/install k0s, am a bit unsure because the existing k0s.yaml seems to have very little config parameters as compared to the sample given in the link .

EDIT: Using [Documentation](https://docs.k0sproject.io/main/configuration/) I have proceeded to generate a new k0s.yaml that uses the existing default settings. Turns out it overwrites the existing k0s.yaml (given above) : I have also effected changes to the new yaml file to produce this :

```
apiVersion: k0s.k0sproject.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: k0s
spec:
  api:
    address: 10.XXX.XXX.XXX
    k0sApiPort: 9443
    port: 6443
    sans:
    - 10.XX.XX.XXX
    - 172.XX.XX.XXX
    - 10.XX.XX.XXX
    - 10.XX.XX.XXX
    - fe80::XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX
    - fe80::XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX
    - fe80::XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX
    - fe80::XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX
    - fe80::XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX
    - fe80::XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX
    tunneledNetworkingMode: false
  controllerManager: {}
  extensions:
    helm:
      charts: null
      repositories: null
    storage:
      create_default_storage_class: true
      type: openebs_local_storage
  images:
    calico:
      cni:
        image: docker.io/calico/cni
        version: v3.21.2
      kubecontrollers:
        image: docker.io/calico/kube-controllers
```

After this change I proceed to do a reinstall of the cluster (with the new config) :

```
k0s install controller -c /etc/k0s/k0s.yaml
```

but I am now getting an error :

```
Error: failed to install k0s service: failed to install service: Init already exists: /etc/systemd/system/k0scontroller.service
```

Comment: Could you please give more details on your issue to reproduce it - do you use k0s on any cloud or on bare metal?

Comment: Bare metal server Debian 10

Comment: Im following this guide https://techviewleo.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-debian-using-k0s/

Comment: @anarxz Suggestion is to do sudo systemctl restart k0scontroller . I have run this command but still k0s kubectl get storageclass returns No resources found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue - in order to re-install the cluster with the new configuration for OpenEBS storage, you'll need to clean up your prior set-up:

1. Stop the k0s service.

```yaml
sudo k0s stop
```

2. Reset previous installation that was done without your customized config file:

```yaml
sudo k0s reset
```

3. Re-install k0s with your new config file and with `--enable-worker` flag -> so that single node k0s with controller and worker functions will be installed again:

```yaml
sudo k0s install controller --enable-worker -c /etc/k0s/k0s.yaml
```

4. Start the k0s service:

```yaml
sudo k0s start
```

5. After a few seconds, check that two storage classes are enabled on the cluster for you to use:

```yaml
sudo k0s kubectl get storageclass
```

The storage classes will have `volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer` - meaning, that there is delay for volume binding until application pod is scheduled on the node.

Comment: noted thanks , I was still in the middle of troubleshooting , let me work on that